# How to use config:publish when package is in the workbench?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I developed a package using artisan's workbench scaffolding tool. I created the file: `src/config/config.php`, and added an array to return some values. As of that point, my package was still in the `workbench` folder. None of the following commands worked:

`$ ./artisan config:publish myvendorname/packagename`

`$ ./artisan config:publish workbench/myvendorname/packagename`

What am I doing wrong? Should I work with Config only after the package is published to `vendor/` (via packagist or otherwise)? Is my option until that point to copy the config directory over manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I   think  you are trying to publish   workbench  config  files

```
php artisan config:publish --path="workbench/vendor/packageName/src/config" vendor/packageName
```

Comment: You're right, but for some reason the directory is getting created and the files are not being copied. But I'm moving over to L5 anyway now so no patience to debug :)

Comment: Yea, there might be several reasons to this .. errors in your config file or path for your workbench package is not correct .